# Import file excel does not enough number

Tags: java, jxl, jexcelapi

I use jxl library to import data from excel. I have a cell with values : **8.628282828**. When i debug as below image :

[image: Debug sheet.getCell(5,i).getContents()]

I see it is type : **NumberRecord** and values is right : **8.628282828**. But when i get content of cell :

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
wbSettings.setEncoding("CP1252");
Workbook w;
w = Workbook.getWorkbook(is, wbSettings);
Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
sheet.getCell(5,i).getContents();
}
```

It's **8.628**
How can i get exactly value of that cell ?

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to a `NumberCell` and get the value as a `double`:

```
double value = ((NumberCell) sheet.getCell(5,i)).getValue();
```

As the documentation for [`Cell.getContents()`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Cell.html#getContents()) states:

> Quick and dirty function to return the contents of this cell as a
>   string. For more complex manipulation of the contents, it is necessary
>   to cast this interface to correct subinterface

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for my question does not clear. I just want it's text, not double. Maybe i can cast double to string like code of you. But i think problem is format cell at file. When i insert character **'** at first : **'8.268282828** is text type in excel. And last i edit format cell in excel file is ok.

Comment: Convert double to string: `Double.toString(value);` Obviously, if it's not a numeric cell, the cast to `NumberCell` will fail. You can get the cell type bye calling [`Cell.getType()`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/CellType.html).

Answer (score 0):

Cast to NumberCell interface and call getValue() to get the double value.